# Initial connection randomly fails with timeout - using 2.2.5 Npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I've been working in the and searching for an answer but have found no solutions yet.  The very first connection randomly fails with a timeout or similar error.  It seems to mainly happen on our Windows 7 client and not Windows 8.  App is .net 4.0. 
If you keep trying eventually it will connect but the users are very frustrated.  Has any solved this or may have info to share?

I've set to allow connections for all users in the conf files, set timeout to 30s, etc.  using md5 as well.  It's totally random at this point.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In postgresql.conf file make tcp_keepalives_idle = 20 to keep your idle connections active. This line is commented by default. [Read this for more details.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-connection.html)
For each 20 seconds this will send keep alive signals for your all idle connections.